# ¿cómo retornar una vista cuando el usuario ha hecho logout en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Intento que cuando el usuario finalice un formulario este haga logout y le retorne una vista de finalizacón disiéndole que ha completado todos los campos correctamente, el problema es cuando intenta hacer logout este me retorna un codigo http `419` y me dice que la pagina ha expirado

```
public function GuardarFormulario(Request $request)
{
     //........
        if(/*...*/){
            //............
        }else{
            $entidad = Entidad::first();
            Session::flash('status', '¡GRACIAS POR REGISTRAR SU INFORMACIÓN '.mb_strtoupper($entidad->nombre));

            Auth::logout();

            $request->session()->invalidate();

            $request->session()->regenerateToken();

            return view('complete');
        }

    }
```

Esto solo me envía un `419` pero tampoco hace logout al usuario, al intentar acceder a rutas protegidas por la autenticación simplemente me permite acceder a dichas rutas.

Comment: Con el siguiente comando: return redirect()->route('Aquí le pasas el nombre de la ruta')

Comment: Gracias, ya habia encontrado la solución, se me había olvidado publicarlo aquí

Answer (score 1):

La solución a mi pregunta es que simplemente no puedo retornar una vista en un controlador que hace parte de una ruta protegida por mi autenticación y además era una ruta de tipo POST, al momento de ejecutar `Auth::logout()` lo que hacía era invalidar mi token de autenticación lo cual generaba el error `419`, lo que me tocó realizar para resolver el problema es redirigir a una ruta publica

```
public function GuardarFormulario(Request $request)
{
     //........
        if(/*...*/){
            //............
        }else{
            $entidad = Entidad::first();
            Session::flash('status', '¡GRACIAS POR REGISTRAR SU INFORMACIÓN '.mb_strtoupper($entidad->nombre));

            Auth::logout();

            $request->session()->invalidate();

            $request->session()->regenerateToken();

            return redirect()->route('logout');
        }

    }
```

dentro de mis rutas

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {
     return view('complete');
})->name('logout');
```